# Excel VBA - when running a stored sub procedure getting runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

The code below taken from Excel 2013 book by John Walkenbach does not run but throws a runtime error 1004 - any ideas?

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim subToCall As String
    
    Select Case VBA.weekDay(Now)
        Case 1, 7
        subToCall = "weekEnd"

        Case Else
        subToCall = "daily"
        
    End Select
    
    Application.Run subToCall
    
End Sub

Sub weekEnd()
    MsgBox "It's the weekend"

End Sub

Sub daily()
     MsgBox "It's a  week day"

End Sub
```

Comment: This code runs for me in Excel/Office 365. What line triggers the error? Is there any more text to the error, other than the code 1004? One interesting thing is that my code changes "weekDay" to "Weekday" ...

Comment: hi it falls over @ the line:   Application.Run subToCall  . 'Application or object defined error'

Comment: Is it one or other of the subToCall functions or both? What other References do you have included: could one of them be using the name 'weekend' or 'daily'?

Comment: Hi I'm pretty new VBA and Excel - however I just got the code to run no problem in a module, previously it had been running (or not running) within the VBA code window of a work sheet. Can you explain why it runs in the former and not the latter?

Comment: See [Where to put the code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

After clarification from the OP, the posted code is in a Worksheet code module, and not a module at global scope. As a consequence the `Application.Run` call cannot find the unqualified function name, and hence the error.

In a global module (under the Modules tab in the VBA Project explorer), the code as written works fine. This is the best place for this type of code, as it is not specific to any particular Worksheet.

If however the code is in a Worksheet module (eg 'Sheet1') (under the Microsoft Excel Objects tab in the VBA Project explorer), then the functions need to be qualified with the name of the sheet, eg `Sheet1.weekEnd` etc.

If you really want this in a Worksheet module, you can amend to:

```
Select Case VBA.weekDay(Now)
    Case 1, 7
    subToCall = Me.Name & ".weekEnd"

    Case Else
    subToCall = Me.Name & ".daily"      
End Select
```

In this case `Me.Name` returns "Sheet1".